# Preventing multiple unnecessary React component code executions

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've built a rather large project with dozens of components. For the most part performance is good, but what I don't like is that component life cycle methods and subsequently rendering get called multiple times in quick succession. Due to the heavily nested nature of my components and the fact that I have many functions that call back into parent components and possibly update state I'm getting these changes to state which can sometimes trigger updates to props downstream.

Are there patterns or practices that can help get this stuff under control? I need more than shouldComponentUpdate; I don't want only to prevent the render call. I also want to prevent any functions of the component from being called multiple times unnecessarily.

I've tried stuff like having a property, for example isGettingData, and checking that or using timing loops but none of these things are fixing the core issue. The decoupled and async nature of react makes getting unwanted component execution under control very hard.

Comment: Are you using the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method?

Comment: I would like to prevent not only the render function from being called, but also any other life cycle functions. In other words I would like the component's code to only run once.

Comment: Have you profiled this? Are you certain that an actual performance problem exists due to lifecycle methods being called?

Comment: As an example I have some network data requests that run inside of the componentWillReceiveProps call. This issue causes those calls to be made multiple times which later triggers updates to some state objects which causes re-renders. I do some checks within componentWillReceiveProps, but because these are async network calls the fields checked are not necessarily updated by the time the componentWillReceiveProps function is called again.